# How do you prevent a TextFieldTableCell from going into Edit mode when pressing the ENTER key?

Tags: java, javafx, tablecell

By default, pressing ENTER on a `TextFieldTableCell` puts the cell into editing mode and draws a textField in the cell. How do I prevent this? I would only like the cell to enter Editing mode if a digit key is pressed. If ENTER is pressed, then it should simply select the cell below.

What I have tried:

```
tableView.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        TablePosition tp;
        if(event.getCode().isDigitKey()) {
            lastKey = event.getText();
            tp = tableView.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
            tableView.edit(tp.getRow() , tp.getTableColumn());
        }
        if(tableView.getEditingCell() == null && event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
            event.consume();
            tableView.getSelectionModel().selectBelowCell();
        }
    }
});
```

The cell still enters Editing mode.

Comment: to solve the part for using a key different from enter: implement your own .. the behavior is hard-coded in CellUtils.createTextField. The rest is more complex (one problem per question, please :)

Comment: oops .. mis-read the enter key part (last comment is about using enter to commit ;) - to not start an edit, you'll have to remove the enter binding from the table's behavior: there is no clean way to do so, but hacks around (reflectively access the behavior from the skin, then modify its inputMap as needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to manually install filters/handlers on the table is to tweak the table's InputMap. Beware: that's private api, requires access to internal packages (inputmap and behavior) and reflective grabbing of the behavior from the skin. Hopefully, those packages will make it into public scope soon.

The basic approach is

- grab the behavior and its inputMap from the skin
- remove the keyMappings you want to replace
- add new keyMappings as needed

In code:

```
TableViewSkin<?> skin = (TableViewSkin<?>) table.getSkin();
// use your favorite utility method to reflectively access the private field
TableViewBehavior<?> listBehavior = (TableViewBehavior<?>) FXUtils.invokeGetFieldValue(
        TableViewSkin.class, skin, "behavior");
InputMap<?> map = listBehavior.getInputMap();
// remove old mapping for enter
Optional<Mapping<?>> mapping = map.lookupMapping(new KeyBinding(ENTER));
map.getMappings().remove(mapping.get());
// add new mapping for enter
map.getMappings().add(new KeyMapping(KeyCode.ENTER, e -> table.getSelectionModel().selectBelowCell()));
// add mappings for digits
EventHandler<KeyEvent> handler = e -> {
    TablePosition<T, ?> pos = table.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell() ;
    if (pos != null ) {
        table.edit(pos.getRow(), pos.getTableColumn());
    }
};
List<KeyMapping> digitMappings = Arrays.stream(KeyCode.values())
        .filter(c -> c.isDigitKey())
        .map(c -> new KeyMapping(c, handler))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                
map.getMappings().addAll(digitMappings);
```

Obviously, this requires that the table's skin is available and that it is of type TableViewSkin. To use, it can be invoked in a listener to the table's skin property:

```
table.skinProperty().addListener(c -> {
    tweakInputMap(table);
});
```

Should work in fx versions >= fx9 (my context is fx17/18 dev) and requires add-exports of inputmap/behavior packages at compile time and add-opens of these packages at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just use an `Event Filter` to prevent going in editing mode on enter key pressed (and to select the cell below):

```java
tableView.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyEvent -> {
    if(keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
        tableView.getSelectionModel().selectBelowCell();
        keyEvent.consume();
    }
});
```

Start editing mode on digit key pressed:

```java
tableView.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
    TablePosition<Person, ?> pos = tableView.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell() ;
    if (pos != null && event.getCode().isDigitKey()) {
        tableView.edit(pos.getRow(), pos.getTableColumn());
    }
});
```

**Edit: Included example**

```java
package org.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class TableViewTestApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createTableView()));
        stage.show();
    }

    private TableView<Item> createTableView() {
        TableView<Item> tableView = new TableView<>();
        tableView.setEditable(true);
        tableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

        TableColumn<Item, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("name");
        tableView.getColumns().add(nameCol);

        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());

        nameCol.setCellFactory(c -> new CustomTableCell());

        // Enter edit mode on digit pressed only
        tableView.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            TablePosition<Item, ?> pos = tableView.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
            if (pos != null && event.getCode().isDigitKey()) {
                tableView.edit(pos.getRow(), pos.getTableColumn());
            }
        });

        tableView.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyEvent -> {
            if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                tableView.getSelectionModel().selectBelowCell(); //***When last cell of column move to the first cell of next column maybe
                keyEvent.consume();
            }
        });

        IntStream.range(1, 5).forEach(i -> tableView.getItems().add(new Item("Item " + i)));

        return tableView;
    }

    private class CustomTableCell extends TableCell<Item, String> {

        private TextField textField;

        private void createTextField() {
            textField = new TextField(getItem());

            // Commit value on focus lost:
            textField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
                if (wasFocused) {
                    commitEdit(textField.getText());
                }
            });

            // This is needed to commit last cell of the column on enter released:
            // (***Alternative: Move to first cell of next column)
            textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, keyEvent -> {
                if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    commitEdit(getItem());
                    keyEvent.consume();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            super.startEdit();
            setText(null);
            createTextField();
            setGraphic(textField);
            textField.requestFocus();
            textField.selectAll();
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();
            setText(getItem());
            setGraphic(null);
        }

        // See: https://gist.github.com/james-d/be5bbd6255a4640a5357
        @Override
        public void commitEdit(String item) {
            // This block is necessary to support commit on losing focus, because the baked-in mechanism
            // sets our editing state to false before we can intercept the loss of focus.
            // The default commitEdit(...) method simply bails if we are not editing...
            if (!isEditing() && !item.equals(getItem())) {
                TableView<Item> table = getTableView();
                if (table != null) {
                    TableColumn<Item, String> column = getTableColumn();
                    TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Item, String> event = new TableColumn.CellEditEvent<>(table,
                            new TablePosition<>(table, getIndex(), column),
                            TableColumn.editCommitEvent(), item);
                    Event.fireEvent(column, event);
                }
            }
            super.commitEdit(item);
            setText(item);
            setGraphic(null);
            textField = null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item == null || empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(item);
            }
        }
    }

    private class Item {

        private final StringProperty name;

        public Item(String name) {
            this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name.set(name);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

**Edit 2: Added custom table cell for Integer (with Spinner)**

```java
package org.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.WritableValue;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.converter.IntegerStringConverter;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParsePosition;
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class TableViewTestApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TableView<Item> tableView = createTableView();
        Button btn = new Button("print items to console");
        btn.setOnAction(actionEvent -> tableView.getItems().forEach(System.out::println));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(tableView, btn)));
        stage.show();
    }

    private TableView<Item> createTableView() {
        TableView<Item> tableView = new TableView<>();
        tableView.setEditable(true);
        tableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

        TableColumn<Item, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("name");
        tableView.getColumns().add(nameCol);

        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());

        nameCol.setCellFactory(c -> new StringTextFieldTableCell());

        // Enter edit mode on digit pressed only
        tableView.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            TablePosition<Item, ?> pos = tableView.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
            if (pos != null && event.getCode().isDigitKey()) {
                tableView.edit(pos.getRow(), pos.getTableColumn());
            }
        });

        tableView.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyEvent -> {
            if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                tableView.getSelectionModel().selectBelowCell(); //***When last cell of column move to the first cell of next column maybe
                keyEvent.consume();
            }
        });

        IntStream.range(1, 5).forEach(i -> tableView.getItems().add(new Item("Item " + i)));

        TableColumn<Item, Integer> quantityCol = new TableColumn<>("quantity");
        quantityCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().quantityProperty().asObject());
        quantityCol.setCellFactory(c -> new IntegerSpinnerTableCell<>());
        quantityCol.setMinWidth(150);
        tableView.getColumns().add(quantityCol);

        return tableView;
    }

    private class StringTextFieldTableCell extends TableCell<Item, String> {

        private TextField textField;

        private void createTextField() {
            textField = new TextField(getItem());

            // Commit value on focus lost:
            textField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
                if (wasFocused) {
                    commitEdit(textField.getText());
                }
            });

            // This is needed to commit last cell of the column on enter released:
            // (***Alternative: Move to first cell of next column)
            textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, keyEvent -> {
                if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    commitEdit(getItem());
                    keyEvent.consume();
                }
            });
        }

        // set the text of the text field and display the graphic
        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            super.startEdit();
            setText(null);
            createTextField();
            setGraphic(textField);
            textField.requestFocus();
            textField.selectAll();
        }

        // revert to text display
        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();
            setText(getItem());
            setGraphic(null);
        }

        // See: https://gist.github.com/james-d/be5bbd6255a4640a5357
        @Override
        public void commitEdit(String item) {
            // This block is necessary to support commit on losing focus, because the baked-in mechanism
            // sets our editing state to false before we can intercept the loss of focus.
            // The default commitEdit(...) method simply bails if we are not editing...
            if (!isEditing() && !item.equals(getItem())) {
                TableView<Item> table = getTableView();
                if (table != null) {
                    TableColumn<Item, String> column = getTableColumn();
                    TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Item, String> event = new TableColumn.CellEditEvent<>(table,
                            new TablePosition<>(table, getIndex(), column),
                            TableColumn.editCommitEvent(), item);
                    Event.fireEvent(column, event);
                }
            }
            super.commitEdit(item);
            setText(item);
            setGraphic(null);
            textField = null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item == null || empty)
                setText(null);
            else
                setText(item);
        }
    }

    public class IntegerSpinnerTableCell<T> extends TableCell<T, Integer> {

        private final Spinner<Integer> spinner;
        private final SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory valueFactory;
        private boolean ignoreUpdate;

        public IntegerSpinnerTableCell() {
            spinner = new Spinner<>();
            valueFactory = new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(1, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1, 1);
            spinner.setValueFactory(valueFactory);
            spinner.setEditable(true);
            NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
            UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> filter = c -> {
                if (c.isContentChange()) {
                    ParsePosition parsePosition = new ParsePosition(0);
                    format.parse(c.getControlNewText(), parsePosition);
                    if (parsePosition.getIndex() == 0 || parsePosition.getIndex() < c.getControlNewText().length()) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                return c;
            };

            TextFormatter<Integer> intFormatter = new TextFormatter<>(new IntegerStringConverter(), 1, filter);
            spinner.getEditor().setTextFormatter(intFormatter);

            spinner.valueProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (!ignoreUpdate) {
                    ignoreUpdate = true;
                    WritableValue<Number> property = (WritableValue<Number>) getTableColumn()
                            .getCellObservableValue(getTableRow().getItem());
                    property.setValue(newValue);
                    ignoreUpdate = false;
                }
            });

            spinner.getEditor().addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, keyEvent -> {
                if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    commitEdit(getItem());
                    keyEvent.consume();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item == null || empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if (isEditing()) {
                    ignoreUpdate = true;
                    setText(null);
                    valueFactory.setValue(item);
                    setGraphic(spinner);
                    ignoreUpdate = false;
                } else {
                    ignoreUpdate = true;
                    setText(String.valueOf(item));
                    setGraphic(null);
                    ignoreUpdate = false;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            if (!isEmpty()) {
                super.startEdit();
                ignoreUpdate = true;
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(spinner);
                valueFactory.setValue(getItem());
                requestEditorAndSelectText(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                ignoreUpdate = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();
            setText(String.valueOf(getItem()));
            setGraphic(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void commitEdit(Integer newValue) {
            if (!isEditing()) {
                TableView<T> table = getTableView();
                if (table != null) {
                    TableColumn<T, Integer> column = getTableColumn();
                    TableColumn.CellEditEvent<T, Integer> event = new TableColumn.CellEditEvent<>(table,
                            new TablePosition<>(table, getIndex(), column),
                            TableColumn.editCommitEvent(), spinner.getValue());
                    Event.fireEvent(column, event);
                }
            }
            super.commitEdit(newValue);
            setText(String.valueOf(newValue.intValue()));
            setGraphic(null);
        }

        private void requestEditorAndSelectText(int maxTries) {
            if (maxTries > 0) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                            if (!spinner.getEditor().isFocused()) {
                                spinner.getEditor().requestFocus();
                                spinner.getEditor().selectAll();
                                requestEditorAndSelectText(maxTries - 1);
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
        }
    }

    private class Item {

        private final StringProperty name;
        private final IntegerProperty quantity;

        public Item(String name) {
            this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
            this.quantity = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getName() + " | " + getQuantity();
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name.set(name);
        }

        public int getQuantity() {
            return quantity.get();
        }

        public IntegerProperty quantityProperty() {
            return quantity;
        }

        public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
            this.quantity.set(quantity);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

**Edit 3: Added example for IntegerTextFieldTableCell (without Spinner, TextField only):**

```java
package org.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.converter.IntegerStringConverter;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParsePosition;
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class TableWithPlainTextFieldTableCellForIntTestApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        TableView<Item> tableView = new TableView<>();
        tableView.setEditable(true);
        tableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

        TableColumn<Item, Integer> quantityCol = new TableColumn<>("quantity");
        tableView.getColumns().add(quantityCol);

        quantityCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().quantityProperty().asObject());
        quantityCol.setCellFactory(c -> new IntegerTextFieldTableCell());
        // Enter edit mode on digit pressed only

        tableView.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            TablePosition<Item, ?> pos = tableView.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
            if (pos != null && event.getCode().isDigitKey()) {
                tableView.edit(pos.getRow(), pos.getTableColumn());
            }
        });

        tableView.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyEvent -> {
            if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                tableView.getSelectionModel().selectBelowCell();
                keyEvent.consume();
            }
        });

        IntStream.range(1, 5).forEach(i -> tableView.getItems().add(new Item()));

        quantityCol.setMinWidth(150);

        Button printBtn = new Button("print items");
        printBtn.setOnAction(actionEvent -> tableView.getItems().forEach(System.out::println));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(tableView, printBtn)));
        stage.show();
    }

    class IntegerTextFieldTableCell extends TableCell<Item, Integer> {

        private TextField textField;

        private void createTextField() {
            textField = new TextField(getItem().toString());

            // Commit value on focus lost:
            textField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
                if (wasFocused) {
                    try {
                        commitEdit(Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()));
                    } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {
                        commitEdit(1);
                    }
                }
            });

            // This is needed to commit last cell of the column on enter released:
            // (***Alternative: Move to first cell of next column)
            textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, keyEvent -> {
                if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    commitEdit(getItem());
                    keyEvent.consume();
                }
            });

            NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
            UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> filter = c -> {
                if (c.isContentChange()) {
                    ParsePosition parsePosition = new ParsePosition(0);
                    format.parse(c.getControlNewText(), parsePosition);
                    if (parsePosition.getIndex() == 0 || parsePosition.getIndex() < c.getControlNewText().length()) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                return c;
            };
            TextFormatter<Integer> intFormatter = new TextFormatter<>(new IntegerStringConverter(), 1, filter);
            textField.setTextFormatter(intFormatter);
        }

        // set the text of the text field and display the graphic
        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            super.startEdit();
            setText(null);
            createTextField();
            setGraphic(textField);
            textField.requestFocus();
            textField.selectAll();
        }

        // revert to text display
        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();
            setText(getItem().toString());
            setGraphic(null);
        }

        // See: https://gist.github.com/james-d/be5bbd6255a4640a5357
        @Override
        public void commitEdit(Integer item) {
            // This block is necessary to support commit on losing focus, because the baked-in mechanism
            // sets our editing state to false before we can intercept the loss of focus.
            // The default commitEdit(...) method simply bails if we are not editing...
            if (!isEditing() && !item.equals(getItem())) {
                TableView<Item> table = getTableView();
                if (table != null) {
                    TableColumn<Item, Integer> column = getTableColumn();
                    TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Item, Integer> event = new TableColumn.CellEditEvent<>(table,
                            new TablePosition<>(table, getIndex(), column),
                            TableColumn.editCommitEvent(), item);
                    Event.fireEvent(column, event);
                }
            }
            super.commitEdit(item);
            setText(item.toString());
            setGraphic(null);
            textField = null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item == null || empty)
                setText(null);
            else
                setText(item.toString());
        }
    }

    class Item {

        private final IntegerProperty quantity = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1);

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return quantity.get() + "";
        }

        public int getQuantity() {
            return quantity.get();
        }

        public IntegerProperty quantityProperty() {
            return quantity;
        }

        public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
            this.quantity.set(quantity);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: good idea - with a catch: consuming the enter in the filter disables the commit after an edit

Comment: Unfortunately adding an Event Filter yields the same results as the original code posted. Cell still goes into editing mode.

Comment: @kleopatra the commit after edit is taken care of in a custom TextFieldTableCell. So that's not an issue.

Comment: hmm ..  I tried the code and it _is_ an issue -  which is expected, as the filter consumes the enter before it ever reaches the textfield. You can quickly very by writing a [mcve] with an editable number column, add the code from this answer, start an edit in the number cell, change the value, press enter: the cell value is reverted to what it was before the edit, the selection is move a row down.

Comment: ahh ... I see: you have a cell hacking for commit-on-focusLost - with a plain TextFieldTableCell, it's behaving as I described in my last comment. You might consider to add that to your answer .

Comment: I added a second example with a custom spinner table cell for int values and the value is not "getting reverted to what it was before the edit".

Comment: "with a plain __TextFieldTableCell__, it's behaving as I described in my last comment" .. your examples use hacky custom cells (fine, as a workaround for missing core functionality) which are __required__ to make this approach working. Adding more of them doesn't make this approach work with core textField cells.

Comment: Not working with default implementation `TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn()`: Yes. Working with my hacky custom cells: Yes.