# How to modify horizontal scrolling behavior after hitting TAB in JavaFX TableView?

Tags: javafx

I'd like to change horizontal scrolling behavior in JavaFX `TableView`.

First, as context, I added the following key events:

1. When user hits TAB, cell on the right of current cell becomes new current cell. When at the very last column of the line, hitting TAB again will select the very first column on the next line. If current cell is in last row and last column, hitting TAB will select cell in first row and first column.
2. Inverse behavior is implemented when hitting SHIFT-TAB. Instead of going right, it goes left.

This behavior was easily implemented, playing with indexes and using `TableView.scrollToColumn()` and `TableView.scrollTo()`.

The behavior I want to modify only occurs when a `TableView` has more columns then the number of columns that can be displayed. I would like to change scroll behavior when current cell is in the far right displayed column. Actually, hitting TAB will scroll to next column, but this new current column will become first displayed column on the left.

Instead, I'd prefer that hitting TAB when current cell is in the far right column displays next column as the last displayed column (far right) instead of first displayed column on the left.

This is exactly actual behavior when SHIFT-TAB is pressed. Going left displays newly selected column as the first displayed column. I'd like to replicate this behavior when going right in a `TableView`.

Any clues how to do it?

Regards.

Comment: try to tweak the mappings in the inputMap installed by the table's behavior

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks for your reply. Tweaking mapping seems interesting, but I have no idea where to find them...

Comment: it's internal api (unfortunately didn't make it into public scope during the big overhaul for fx9 ;) - com.sun.javafx.control.behavior and xx.inputmap, relatively stable and simple to use, though.

Comment: I think the `tab` key will, by default, change focus, so perhaps providing a customized [TableViewFocusModel](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#setFocusModel(javafx.scene.control.TableView.TableViewFocusModel)) for your table might help you progress towards a solution (I don't know though).

Comment: @jewelsea no, the focusmodel is unrelated to focustraversal (which is the default mapping to Tab)

Comment: an example of [how to tweak an inputMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68649724/how-do-you-prevent-a-textfieldtablecell-from-going-into-edit-mode-when-pressing/68653647#68653647)

Answer (score 1):

This answer isn't a full answer to your problem but you only requested clues for a solution, which is what this is and it is easier to put this as an answer rather than as a series of comments.

Possible solutions:

1. Modify the table view behavior input map.
2. Remap the key events routed to the table.

Perhaps you might need a combination of some of the above to get what you want.

**1. Modify the table view behavior input map**

This is the solution suggested by kleopatra in comments:

> try to tweak the mappings in the inputMap installed by the table's behavior

For a bit more info on the behavior implementation, see the answer to:

- [cannot find symbol BehaviorSkinBase (from javafx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69443315/cannot-find-symbol-behaviorskinbase-from-javafx/69458209#69458209)

It includes a [link to the current behavior source](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/tree/fdc88341f1df8fb9c99356ada54b25124b77ea6e/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/behavior) and information on how you might go about tweaking it for your application.

The implementation of this approach is a little tricky because it is part of the internal `com.sun` API for JavaFX, which perhaps should not be directly used, as your application may break without warning in future JavaFX versions if you use it.

**2. Remap the key events routed to the table.**

Perhaps the technique of filtering input events in this answer:

- [JavaFX HTMLEditor over-ride default typing behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68945914/javafx-htmleditor-over-ride-default-typing-behaviour/)

might help you get the solution you want.  However, again, I'm not sure.

You would need to do more work than that solution.

In addition to filtering the <kbd>tab</kbd> key, you would need to fire off a new artificial event to create <kbd>shift+tab</kbd> event.

And you would need to ensure that the filtering is done at the appropriate level (the capturing of the event for focus handling for tab might be at the scene level rather than the table view itself).